# JavaScript fallback for the unsupported column-break-before property

Tags: javascript, css

Does anyone know of a workable substitute for the column-break-before property? Apparently, it's never been supported on any browser, but it would be an extremely useful CSS property to utilize for columned layouts.

I would be happy with a JavaScript or CSS solution if you know of any.

Comment: `webkit` now supports...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice list of polyfills

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

and there is one polyfill for column property in the list

https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn

but it doesnt seem to support column-break-before.

Answer (score 1):

**[Columnflow](http://labs.ft.com/articles/ft-columnflow/)** was released very recently by the Financial Times web team.

Drawback : it was developed for an Android webapp and doesn't really offer support for IE. IE10 only.

Search "keepwithnext" in the documentation : https://github.com/ftlabs/ftcolumnflow for what seems support of `column-break-before`

> Avoid a column or page break after this element; prefer a break before if necessary